# Translation of the phrase “You exist, thus I believe”

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

What is Latin for “You exist, thus I believe”? Please state which dictionary you have used (if you have used any).

Answer (score 4):

Nice and simple: **Es, itaque credo.**

My go-to English-Latin dictionary is Smith & Hall, accessible [here](https://www.latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries).

Comment: I would say "Tu es," since I would guess that the person is particularly important to @Jjj. The "Tu" would serve to emphasize the 'you' in their English translation.

Comment: Perhaps *ergo* would be better, since (I suspect) the OP is thinking of Descartes' "cogito ergo sum"